# rhc snapshot not saving all the data

Tags: django, openshift, openshift-client-tools

If I try to take a snapshot

```
rhc snapshot save -a django
```

It is not saving all the data and codes in the server.

Here is the link of  my app

http://django-appspot.rhcloud.com

It is running on:

Django-1.5.1
python-2.7
Mysql

The size without `/tmp` , `/ssh` , `/sandbox` is 866M

I think I am exceeding the disk quota.

Currently I am unable to take the media folder backup. Is there any way around??

Answer (score 0):

It is Solved

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/rhc-snapshot-not-saving-all-the-data#comment-33800

Use WinFTP to download the backup files